# Can't setState and getState in CConsoleCommand of YII

Tags: php, yii

I've wrote a `CTestCommand extends CConsoleCommand`
that require to call `getState` and `setState` of `CWebUser` or `CUserIdentity`
I don't know whether it use `CWebUser` or `CUserIdentity`
But when I runnng `./yiic test` in the console. It print out

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user()
```

My code is

```
user()->getState('site_id')
```

It's OK when I run in web browser. But it can't be run in command.
My config file is

```
return array(
        'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'name'=>'My Console Application',
        'import'=>array(
        'ext.*',
                'application.models.*',
                'application.components.*',
                'ext.mailer.*',
        ),
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yii console applications usually do not have a user component or - for that matter - a session component configured. While you can configure a user in `protected/config/console.php`, I'm not quite certain if you can do the same with a session. After all, sessions are a web-thing that require cookies to operate.

Comment: This is correct, a Console Application won't access CWebUser by default

Answer (score 0):

Do you rely on a global function file that defines the `user()` method? Is that file being included in your console config?